# Twitter API 1.1 returns authentification error when the search contains the "@" character

Tags: php, twitter

If I pass `test` to the `q` parameter of the `tweets.json` endpoint, it returns data fine. But if I include the `@` symbol at the front, i.e. `@test`, I get the following error:

> Could not authenticate you.

The same issue happens when I use `%40` instead of `@`.

Here is my code:

```
$query = array( // query parameters
    'q' => '@test',
    'count' => '100'
);

$method = "GET";
$path = "/1.1/search/tweets.json";

$token = 'xxxxxx';
$token_secret = 'xxxxxx';
$consumer_key = 'xxxxxxx';
$consumer_secret = 'xxxxxx';

$host = 'api.twitter.com';

$oauth = array(
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'oauth_token' => $token,
    'oauth_nonce' => (string)mt_rand(), // a stronger nonce is recommended
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_version' => '1.0'
);

$oauth = array_map("rawurlencode", $oauth); // must be encoded before sorting
$query = array_map("rawurlencode", $query);

$arr = array_merge($oauth, $query); // combine the values THEN sort

asort($arr); // secondary sort (value)
ksort($arr); // primary sort (key)

// http_build_query automatically encodes, but our parameters
// are already encoded, and must be by this point, so we undo
// the encoding step
$querystring = urldecode(http_build_query($arr, '', '&'));

$url = "https://$host$path";

// mash everything together for the text to hash
$base_string = $method."&".rawurlencode($url)."&".rawurlencode($querystring);

// same with the key
$key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret)."&".rawurlencode($token_secret);

// generate the hash
$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $key, true)));

// this time we're using a normal GET query, and we're only encoding the query params
// (without the oauth params)
$url .= "?".http_build_query($query);
$url=str_replace("&amp;","&",$url); //Patch by @Frewuill

$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $signature; // don't want to abandon all that work!
ksort($oauth); // probably not necessary, but twitter's demo does it

// also not necessary, but twitter's demo does this too
function add_quotes($str) { return '"'.$str.'"'; }
$oauth = array_map("add_quotes", $oauth);

// this is the full value of the Authorization line
$auth = "OAuth " . urldecode(http_build_query($oauth, '', ', '));

// if you're doing post, you need to skip the GET building above
// and instead supply query parameters to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: $auth"),
                  //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

// do our business
$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

return $json;
```

Why can't I retrieve data with the `@` symbol at the front of the `q` parameter?

Comment: @test is actually searching for "referencing person " test. see: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Comment: Yep the idea is to get tweets with the "referencing person" in question

Comment: This seems more of code issue than a twitter issue. The fact that you add `@` gives you a connection error seems quite odd. Also if you're looking for an individual, why not access [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, this is a double (even triple) encoding issue. I managed to get it working in 2 separate ways (they must not be used together):

1. Merging before `rawurlencode()`, my preferred solution:

   ```
   //NOPE $oauth = array_map("rawurlencode", $oauth); // must be encoded before sorting
   //NOPE $query = array_map("rawurlencode", $query);

   $arr = array_merge($oauth, $query); // combine the values THEN sort
   $arr = array_map("rawurlencode", $arr);

   asort($arr); // secondary sort (value)
   ksort($arr); // primary sort (key)
   ```
2. Removing `urldecode()` after the `http_build_query()`:

   ```
   $querystring = (http_build_query($arr, '', '&'));
   ```

But at this point, I could not explain why either of them worked. It turns out that later in the code, you use this:

```
// this time we're using a normal GET query, and we're only encoding the query params
// (without the oauth params)
$url .= "?".http_build_query($query);
```

The subtle difference is that this time you did not use `urldecode()` after `http_build_query()`.

Because of all the encoding that goes on, the url you end up using for the signature does not match the url you use for the request, therefore failing the authentification.

> **Signature**
>   The `oauth_signature` parameter contains a value which is generated by running all of the other request parameters and two secret values through a signing algorithm. The purpose of the signature is so that Twitter can verify that the request has not been modified in transit, verify the application sending the request, and verify that the application has authorization to interact with the user’s account.

From [Authorizing a request - Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests).

This works, the url is encoded 2 times and the signature url 3 times:

```
// end of $url, encoded twice
?q=%2540test&count=100
// end of $base_string, used in signature, encoded thrice
%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26q%3D%252540test
```

This doesn't, the url is encoded 1 time and the signature url 3 times:

```
// end of $url
?q=%40test&count=100
// end of $base_string, used in signature
%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26q%3D%252540test
```

Because the signature must only be encoded one more time than the request url, both previously mentioned solutions work (independently) because:

- Solution 1 doesn't encode `$query`, making `$url` single encoded and the signature double encoded.
- Solution 2 keeps the double encoding, leaving `$url` double encoded and making the signature triple encoded.

But wait, why does it only fail when using `@` ?

Because that's the only character in all the parameters that actually needs encoding. It is encoded when using `http_build_query()`, generating a `%` character that will get caught up in subsequent encodings.

Comment: wow thanks for that answer. I tried your first solution and it worked fine. I tell you what, they couldnt make calling their API any more complex than what it is.  In two hours, ill give you the +50 when stackoverflow allows me to